# Reference for ring structure on Thom spectra

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology

I have been asked to provide at reference for the fact that if $X\to B(BG)$ (where $G$ is the stable auto-homotopy-uquivalences of spheres - or $BG=Pic(S)$ in some peoples terminology) then the Thom spectrum associated to the based loop map

$$ \Omega X \to BG=Pic(S) $$

is a ring-spectrum. I was looking around for a good reference, but couldn't find one that was very clean cut (the paper is about something in symplectic geometry - so I would like the reference to be precise). I also don't know where this originally appeared - so I would prefer the original reference if it is clear or a reference that points back to the original.

Comment: A small correction: if $G$ is the stable auto-homotopy equivalences of spheres (what's usually called $F$ or $GL_1(\mathbb{S})$) then $BG$ is only the connected component at the identity of $Pic(\mathbb{S})$. Of course this does not change anything important.

Comment: Are you are saying that $Pic(S)=\mathbb{Z}\times BG$?

Comment: As a space, yes. I don't know if they split as groups though (that is I don't think there's a section $\mathbb{Z}\to Pic(\mathbb{S})$ picking one sphere per connected component, but I'm not sure)

Comment: What's your map $\Omega BBG\to BG$? I am only aware of a map in the opposite direction

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე If $G$ is commutative (more generally an $E_2$-space) $\Omega BBG\cong BG$ since $BG$ is connected and so group-like

Comment: @DenisNardin I was not aware that auto-homotopy-equivalences of spheres stably commute! Can you give me a reference to read about it?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე I personally like this a lot: https://arxiv.org/abs/1403.4320, I am sure that there are a lot of other accounts. Basically it boils down to the fact that the sphere spectrum is an $E_\infty$-ring spectrum.

Comment: (cont) The analogy to keep in mind is that, for a general $R$-module $M$, $\mathrm{Aut}(M)$ need not be commutative, but when $M$ is free of rank one, $\mathrm{Aut}(M)=R^\times$ and so it is commutative.

Comment: Obviously, Denis cannot possibly mean ``commutative'' to mean commutative!  A grouplike commutative topological monoid is equivalent to a product of Eilenberg-MacLane spaces, which $F$ and $SF$ emphatically are not.   It is ancient that $F$ and $SF$ are $E_{\infty}$ spaces, that is homotopy commutative with all possible higher homotopy commutativity.  See e.g. [20] and, for calculations, [17] on http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/PAPERS1965.html

Comment: @PeterMay Obviously I meant $E_\infty$ (that is commutative up to infinitely many coherences). This is obviously in contrast with the traditional terminology that you are referring to, but it is gaining traction and I think it is more intuitive. What you called commutative I usually call *strictly commutative*, to distinguish it (they are, as you note, very different concepts). I am sorry for any confusion that this somewhat non-standard choice of words may have caused.

Comment: On the level of spectra, I remember an old phone conversation with Jeff Smith, in which he advocated changing commutative ring spectrum from its traditional up to homotopy meaning to $E_{\infty}$-ring spectrum.  That makes more sense since strictly commutative ring spectra are rare and uninteresting, unlike commutative topological monoids.

Comment: @PeterMay I think this terminology for commutative monoids is forced upon you by the one on commutative ring spectra if you want the group of units of a commutative ring spectrum to be a commutative monoid (and I at least do). That said this, as all conventions, is mostly a matter of personal taste.

Answer (score 10):

I think that the original paper is

> [Mahowald - Ring spectra that are Thom complexes](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.dmj/1077313574)

My favorite reference for the multiplicative properties of Thom spectra is

> [Antolín-Camarena, Barthel - A simple universal property of Thom ring spectra](https://arxiv.org/abs/1411.7988)

Answer (score 9):

The late Gaunce Lewis's 1978 PhD thesis ``The stable category and generalized Thom spectra'' proved (as a special case) that the Thom spectra of $F$ and its oriented version $SF$ (alias $GL_1(S)$ or $SL_1(S)$) are $E_{\infty}$ ring spectra, the most highly structured kind of ring spectrum.  The published version is Chapter IX of Springer LNS 1213, http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/BOOKS/equi.pdf, which was written so as to be as independent as possible of the previous chapters.

Answer (score 2):

Along the great references cited above, I think

Mahowald, Mark; Ray, Nigel
A note on the Thom isomorphism. (English) Zbl 0469.55007
Proc. Am. Math. Soc. 82, 307-308 (1981).

is also a good reference. Theorem 1 of this paper, proved as Corollary 3, is what you are after. I must add that Theorem 1 of this paper was originally proved in "Mahowald. Ring spectra that are Thom complexes" that is cited above.

I also like to add that Thom spectrum of a map from a loop space into $BG$ is not necessarily a ring spectrum! The statement is that the Thom spectrum of any $H$-map, in particular loop map, is a ring spectrum.